# How to implements Model in View when Linq Query is Distinct type in Action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

Hi I am facing a problem in view code

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Testing()

    {
        //var res = (from empname in db.UserMasters
        //              select empname.EmployeeId).Distinct().ToList();
        var res = db.UserMasters.Select(x=>x.EmployeeId).Distinct().ToList();
        return View(res);
    }
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<TaskShedular.Models.UserMaster>
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Testing";
    }
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li><a href="#">@item.EmployeeId</a></li>
    }
```

**Error**

[image: Error ScreeShot]

Answer (score 1):

Add a `ToList` in your query (it's more usual to pass an `IEnumerable<T>` rather than a `DbQuery<T>`)

```
var res = db.UserMasters.Select(x=>x.EmployeeId).Distinct().ToList();
```

and change  in your View

```
@model IEnumerable<string>
```

Cause if your select just `EmployeeId`, you will get a collection of `string`, not a collection of `TaskShedular.Models.UserMaster`

then

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <li><a href="#">@item</a></li>
    }
```